# GraphQL: Fetch DB column to different ObjectType field property

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

is it possible in GraphQL to have a different field property name then the column name in a database?

For example:
A user has a ID. In the database the column name of the ID is `id_user`. But in GraphQL i want to access it just with `id`.

Is there something like an alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SQL call you can assign an alias to your column, like so:

```
SELECT id_user AS id FROM users_table
```

Alternatively your resolver can take the query result and rename the field.
I'd only do this if you're using something like MongoDB where you can't assign aliases to columns.

If you're looking to do this in GraphQL then you would have to do it on the client side by assigning the alias to the field:

```
user {
  id: id_user
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's a great idea. This should work for me. ;)